# ExecutorService miss calls

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with ExecutorService, it does not execute all calls.

```java
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidConnection, InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        XMLUrlService xmlUrlService = new XMLUrlService();
        LinkedBlockingQueue<String> linkedBlockingQueue = xmlUrlService.getAllXMLUrls();

        System.out.println(linkedBlockingQueue.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < linkedBlockingQueue.size(); i++) {

            executor.execute(new XMLParser(linkedBlockingQueue));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

XMLUrlService class returns a list of URLs to which it then performs connections.

XMLPaser is a class that is responsible for making a connection to a given URL.

```java
public class XMLParser implements Runnable {


    private LinkedBlockingQueue queue;

    public XMLParser(LinkedBlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public XMLParser(){}

    public void getRates(String data) throws IOException, XMLStreamException, InvalidConnection {

            URL url = new URL(data);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
    }


    public void run() {
            try {
                String data = (String) queue.take();
                getRates(data);

            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                //Handle exception
            } catch (InvalidConnection invalidConnection) {
                invalidConnection.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

My blocking queue contains 250 different url addresses, but the executorservice performs random number of calls (250 is only random number of elemnts to be tested). I think that when I take items from the queue, I can omit some, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you should change:

**The way you execute the tasks**
You are executing the tasks in a very odd way. Instead of passing `linkedBlockingQueue`, pass the `String` like so:

```
System.out.println(linkedBlockingQueue.size());
for (int i = 0; i < linkedBlockingQueue.size(); i++) {
    String url = linkedBlockingQueue.remove()
    executor.execute(new XMLParser(url));
}
```

**The way you handle exceptions**
Do not swallow exceptions - the easiest way is to use a `Callable` instead to get `Future`s so that you can later check what happened with your tasks:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> linkedBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    System.out.println(linkedBlockingQueue.size());

    List<Future<Void>> result = linkedBlockingQueue.stream().map(
            url -> executor.submit(new XMLParser(url))
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Future<Void> future : result) {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something happened:" + e);
        }
    }

    executor.shutdown();
```

**Waiting for execution**
After you shutdown the executor, wait until all your tasks are done.

```
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: thanks for advice, but my executorservice still miss some calls :/